# Why is the data in variable different when using these two sets of statements?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When I attempt to get the c_str by accessing the result of the type conversion function, parantheses included, the string is empty.

```
const wchar_t* test1 = (type_conversion.string_to_wstring(result1)).c_str();

// test1 contains empty string "";
```

When I use an intermediate variable 'testWstring', the result is different - I have the contents that were originally in 'result1' as I would expect.

```
wstring testWstring = type_conversion.string_to_wstring(result1);

const wchar_t* test1 = testWstring.c_str();

// test1 contains "hi";
```

The typeConversion.string_to_wstring function looks like this:

```
wstring type_conversion::string_to_wstring(const string& str)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int) str.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str.c_str(), slength, 0, 0); 
    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    std::wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}
```

I've obviously misunderstood something here. Coming from a C# background, I would expect the two sets of statements to result in the same value in 'test1'.

Why is this not the case?

Comment: In the first case there is a temporary involved and the wchar_t* will point to something undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of calling string_to_wstring is not bound to a reference or assigned to object. It is destructed at the end of the full-expression. See also [sequence-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

In the second example you assign the result to a variable which is retained in the scope.

Comment: Ugh! I guess I will get used to that. Good link.

Comment: "at the end of the sequence point" makes no sense, particularly considering that the notion of sequence points was removed in C++11. It would even be incorrect to say that the temporary is destroyed at the next sequence point. No, it is destroyed at the end of the _full-expression_.

Comment: Amended. Thanks for the precision.

Answer (score 1):

The result of executing function string_to_wstring is a temporary object. In this statement

```
const wchar_t* test1 = (typeConversion.string_to_wstring(result1)).c_str();
```

it will be deleted when the control will be passed further. So the code has undefined behaviour.

In the second case you are using pointer to internal buffer of an alive object. So until the objevt will be changed the pointer will be valid.